# Removing item from list and adding to another

Tags: c#

I have a list of Stations that I want to rearrange. The way I need to do this is as follows:

Remove the values from one list and move them to another for rearranging.
I need to insert these values in based on their total impact. To do this I want to find the ideal position in an already populated list.

Right now, its based on distance between coordinates. So lets say this is my oldlist:

```
"PO" 1 1
"wSX" 100 150
"JIK" 300 300
"LPO" 200 250
"NJH" 100 350
```

So calculating the distance of these values gives me:
PO -> WSX -> JIK -> LPO -> NJH -> PO = 987 km

And my new list looks like this:

```
"PO" 1 1
"WSX" 100 150
"JIK" 300 300
"PO" 1 1
```

I want to add LPO to index 1 within the list and calculate the distance,
then I want to take it from there and move it to index 2 etc. From there I want to select the variation that gives the shortest total distance and leave it there. Then I move on and try moving the other values until I have no more to move over.

This should give me a viable short distance for a set of stations.

I have tried using a while loop in order to remove and add the stations, which kind of works but I am just not sure how to make it check the other positions aswell.

I also need help with some logical operations in order to determine the variation with the shortest distance.

```
///c#

//Rearrange the list

int value = 0;

while(list.Count != 0)
{
   newlist.Add(oldlist[value]);

   oldlist.RemoveAt(0);
   value++;
}

//find the smaller variation

if (i == 0)
     smallest = value;

else if(value < smallest)
     smallest = value;
```

I mainly just need some help with creating a loop that will follow this route. If there is any additional info you might need, just let me know.

Comment: What's The meaning of the two numbers? E.g. 1/1, 100/150, ...

Comment: Those are X and Y coordinates for the locations.

Answer (score 0):

How about you try to store it in a SortedList?

It should simplify your problem and all you'll need to do is store the distance as the key and your actual object as the value. The SortedList should take care of the rest. Although it might take a little bit more memory.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.sortedlist?view=netframework-4.8